# How can I mock protected method of parent class?

Tags: java, mockito

I try to mock protected method of the parent class. For that reason I use `Mockito` & `PowerMockito`. My parent class.

```
public class Parent {
    protected int foo() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Do not invoke this method.");
    }
}
```

My child class.

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    protected int boo() {
        return super.foo();
    }
}
```

And test class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Parent.class, Child.class})
public class ChildTest {

    @Mock
    private Child childMock;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        initMocks(childMock);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldInvokeProtectedMockedMethod() throws Exception {
        /* Given */
        PowerMockito.doReturn(500).when(childMock, "foo");
        /* When */
        childMock.boo();
        /* Then */
        Mockito.verify(childMock, Mockito.times(1)).boo();
        Mockito.verify(childMock, Mockito.times(1)).foo();
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        Mockito.reset(childMock);
    }
}
```

When I run it I get this error

```
Wanted but not invoked:
child.foo();
-> at com.test.ChildTest.shouldInvokeProtectedMockedMethod(ChildTest.java:36)

However, there were other interactions with this mock:
child.boo();
-> at com.test.ChildTest.shouldInvokeProtectedMockedMethod(ChildTest.java:33)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you just call `foo` and not `super.foo`? I'd expect the same behavior, but when you start mucking with bytecode strange things can happen.

Comment: By mocking `Child`, your `boo` method is a mock implementation, it doesn't actually call `foo`. I think what you want is a Spy.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes.

Comment: If you want to make it a spy, instead of annotating childMock with @ Mock, annotate it with @ Spy. This will call all real methods on the object, but it will return mocked responses when you overrode a response with when().

Comment: I may be wrong, but do you just need to tell Mockito to `callTheRealMethod` on `boo`?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? It's a really terrible idea to do partial mocks. Can you explain what exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Maybe that way we will figure out how to help you without doing terrible hacks?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the foo() method is really called, you dont't need neither Mockito, nor PowerMockito.

Catching the runtime exception informs you that foo() method has been called.

```
package foo.bar;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ChildTest {

    /**
     * child.boo() calls super.foo(), then throws a RuntimeException.
     */
    @Test(expected = RuntimeException.class)
    public void shouldInvokeProtectedMethod() {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.boo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldInvokeProtectedMockedMethod() throws Exception {
    int expected = 1;
    Child childMock = mock(Child.class);
    when(childMock.foo()).thenReturn(expected);
    when(childMock.boo()).thenCallRealMethod();

    childMock.boo();
    org.mockito.Mockito.verify(childMock, org.mockito.Mockito.times(1)).boo();
    org.mockito.Mockito.verify(childMock, org.mockito.Mockito.times(1)).foo();
}
```